# Batch File If command

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, bash, batch

I'm trying to create a batch file for the first time. This will be to download a file that is being update once every week with a new ID. This is the batch file that I have created till now -

```
@echo off
echo open SERVER> temp.txt
echo USERNAME>> temp.txt
echo PWD>> temp.txt
echo cd />> temp.txt
echo cd Events/_PPV_Barker>> temp.txt
echo binary>> temp.txt
echo get Barker*_480i.ts>> temp.txt 
ftp -s:temp.txt
del temp.txt
```

I know that everytime the new file will be uploaded on the server, the start of the file name will be `Barker` and the file name will end with `480i.ts`. I tried * like shown above, but it doesn't work. How can I use the if command to get the file with a unique ID everytime? or is there any other way apart from the if command?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Keshav

Comment: in linux you have access to /dev/random or /dev/urandom or similiar.  You could take 10 bytes from there, and the chances of overlap are slim.  Also maybe you could shim the date in there.  Something like %m %d %y, have to look it up.

Comment: @cybernard It looks like it's an upload to a linux system, so they wouldn't have access to those directories from the batch file.

Comment: Can we see a sample of what unique is, because date and time are unique, but we don't know what the pattern is?

Comment: Is this the only file in the directory that starts "Barker"? Or are there more than one?

Comment: BTW, you are really scripting ftp, not windows batch. The `IF isn't supported in ftp.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, there is a new file each time you access the server, but you don't know the details of its name. What I don't know is whether the file is removed after you down-load it, or whether you have an ever-increasing number of files and you have to choose the latest.

In the simplest case, there is only one file, and here your solution is almost correct: there is one simple change needed, to replace `get` by `mget`, when the wild card `*` will work:-

```
echo mget Barker*_480i.ts>> temp.txt
```

If there many files that match this file mask, then you will down-load an increasing number of files on each access. A quick and dirty fix is to keep the files in your current directory and make them read-only: you will get a lot of errors, but the new file will down-load and you won't have the overhead of transferring the files you have got previously.

If you have full access to the remote directory, then you can delete, move or rename the down-loaded file on the remote, so that you will have only one file each time which matches the file mask.

If you can't do any of these things, then you will need two `ftp` calls: the first will get a directory list from the remote, which you will then compare with your previous remote list, so that you can then identify the new file and build a second `ftp` call to retrieve it. A batch file to do this will not be easy to write, but it's possible - I do things like this when I am processing WebCam files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to place your password and user name in the script (in plain text!) then you shouldn't mind using them on the command line itself.

If you keep local copies of the old files after downloading them, and don't change them, or their timestamps, you can eliminate the whole batch file idea by using [wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), and include the `--timestamping` option. That will compare the size and timestamp of local files with remote files, only downloading remote files when either one is different, or the local file doesn't exist. As an added benefit, if you missed prior updates, it will download all new files, not just the newest one.

Your command line would look something like this:

```
`wget --ftp-user=<user> --ftp-password=<password> --timestamping ftp://example.com/Events/_PPV_Barker/Barker*_480i.ts`
```

Of course, this assumes you have the proper priveleges to install wget, and that you keep the prior copies locally.

Comment: I don't know why when I read your answer I read `winscp` instead of `wget`...

Comment: @Hastur It's been a decade since I've used `winscp`. That said, IIRC, it does have a feature that just might work, instead of writing a batch file. Since the OP listed the `windows` tag, it just might be an option. And `winscp` is able to handle secure FTP. You may have hit on another option for the OP.

Comment: There's a lot of program suitable for it, nonetheless I did not write in my answer the part about `wget` if I didn't misread the command name in your... BTW if you `"` quote the path that command I think it is usable in `bash` without any eventual expansion issue...

Answer (score 0):

try using the:

```
mget
```

command.  I looked it up, and it says get multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

#### Other programs/ ways

Using `ftp` is not secure.
The secure version of ftp is named `ftps`, *ftp secure*. Try to use it instead of `ftp`, if you can.

It's always a good exercise to do your own scripts, but it is better to use the tools created for that purpose when they exist. As alternatives more cosy you can use **`wget`** (see below) that will not require any other server installed remotely.

Since you have access to the remote computer if it is installed you can use **`rsync`** too.
If it misses try to use `scp -p`, or `sftp` taking advantage from the ssh-key<sup>[[4](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)]</sup>.

If you want to stick with `ftp`, use the `mget` option that will blindly copy all the files from the directory, but set in advance the mode of file transfer to binary with the `binary` command.

---

#### Wget

`wget` *- The non-interactive network downloader* <sup>[[1](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm),[2](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)]</sup>. You can use:

```
wget -S -N "ftp://YourSite/Events/_PPV_Barker/Barker*_480i.ts"
```

The option `-N` is to keep timestamps and to download only files newer than the local ones.
The quote `"` may be needed to avoid shell expansion under Linux.
It works under windows too (of course with the windows version of the program).

---

A more complete *commandline* in your case (and in only one line) should be:

```
wget -user=USERNAME -password=PASSWORD 
     -N "ftp://YourSite/Events/_PPV_Barker/Barker*_480i.ts"
```

Of course it is more wise to avoid to write password in your *commandline* or in scripts... you can simply use the self-explaining option `--ask-password` instead.

A more fine solution under Linux is to put the information needed in a file named `.wgetrc`. It should be easy to find the equivalent name in the windows documentation

> ```
> $ cat ~/.wgetrc
> ftp_user=UsernameOnTheRemoteFTP
> ftp_password=PasswordOnTheRemoteFTP
> http_user=UsernameOnTheRemoteHTTP
> http_password=PasswordOnTheRemoteHTTP
> ```

---

You can read from `wget --help`, or from `man wget`:

> **-N,  --timestamping**            don't re-retrieve files unless newer than local
>       **-S, --server-response**           print server response.
>
> **--user=user**
>      **--password=password**
>      Specify the username user and password password for both FTP and HTTP file retrieval.  These parameters can be overridden using the --ftp-user and --ftp-password options for FTP connections and the --http-user and --http-password options for HTTP connections.

---